# python import within directory

Tags: python

I have a python project, I divided it into two parts, a library part and a
binary part.

For organization reasons, I wanted to have a hierarchy like this:

```
project/
    lib/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
    bin/
        binary1.py # contains: import module1
        binary2.py # contains: import module2
    doc/
    ...
```

The problem is, of course, the simple import in binary{1,2}.py doesn't work, at
least in the coding phase (before installation).

Any suggestions? How do you test your code when you're coding?

Comment: you have to add path of project/ or lib/ to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171445/importing-a-module-from-an-upper-directory-within-a-package-when-the-package-is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171445/importing-a-module-from-an-upper-directory-within-a-package-when-the-package-is)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use absolute imports everywhere.

```
project/
    __init__.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
    bin/
        __init__.py
        binary1.py # contains: import module1
        binary2.py # contains: import module2
    doc/
    ...
```

Setting PYTHONPATH to the directory above `project`, you can import `module1` from `binary1.py` like this:

```
from project.lib import module1
```

The `__init__.py` files can make importing simpler, let's say in each file you have a class. Usually you would have to import the class like this (inclduding filename):

```
from project.lib.module1 import Module1
```

But if you edit `lib/__init__.py` to contain this line:

```
from project.lib.module1 import Module1
```

You can use the namespace of `lib` to import `Module1` directly from `lib`:

```
from project.lib import Module1
```

Comment: That was quick, thanks. But how do you manage the PYTHONPATH modification? do you do it on every project, or have you an automatic way to do it ?

Comment: I use `virtualenv` which takes care of that after you activate a virtual environment.